# How to send data through Matlab Events and Listeners?

Tags: matlab, events, asynchronous, real-time, listeners

I have a code which receives information in real-time. Every time it receives this data, I want it to notify another object which has a listener to this event and send the information my first app received. All this asynchronously. Any ideas?

Comment: A good place to start is the [MATLAB documentation for events/listeners](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html).

Comment: I have already been there... no help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have a class 'myClass' that I want to listen to. First, I need to [write my class with an event](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners--syntax-and-techniques.html):

```
classdef myClass < handle
    properties
        % list of properties
    end 

    events
        myEvent
    end

    methods
        % ... we'll write this in a second!
    end
end
```

Then, we build *another* class to contain data we would like to pass through. [This class must inherit from `event.EventData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/event.eventdata.html):

```
classdef myEventData < event.EventData
    properties
        A
        B
        C
    end
    methods
        function obj = myEventData(A, B, C)
            obj.A = A;
            obj.B = B;
            obj.C = C;
        end
    end
 end
```

Then, in a method where you want to pass your data, construct a `myEventData` object and use `notify` to raise the event:

```
 methods
     function getDataAndNotify(obj)
         [A, B, C] = result_of_processing; 
         eventdata = myEventData(A, B, C);
         notify(obj, 'myEvent', eventdata);
     end
 end
```

OK, now your class is set up to broadcast events. How do we listen to it?

Use [`addlistener`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) to set up the listener:

```
M = myClass;

myListener = addListener(M, 'myEvent', {@myListenerCallback});
```

Your callback must have at least two arguments. The first argument is the source of the event; the second is any data the event may have passed.

```
function myListenerCallback(obj, eventdata)
    % ...
end
```

In this case, `obj` will be the `myClass` obj that raised the event, and `eventdata` will be your `myEventData` object that contains the data you passed. Access the data like you would properties of any other object, i.e., `eventdata.A`, `eventdata.B`, `eventdata.C`.

Comment: Thanks, that works if you have a straight forward use of a Listener. What if the event is triggered in a function called by a class, and the listener is in a method of another class, which the object that triggers it is not created in it?

Comment: You need to write a method in your listening class that takes the event class as an argument, and assign the listener there. Basically you're just making a wrapper function around `addlistener`.

Comment: I already did that, thanks! Just got it to work yesterday!! ;)

Comment: @DangKhoa, thanks for the excellent example. But, can you add more on what to fill under the function myListenerCallback. Appreciate it

Comment: Updated link for MATLAB's Events and Listeners Syntax article: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-syntax-and-techniques.html